# How do I generate a tweet with cell values and conditional statements in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to generate a tweet using a bunch of values in google sheet.

My question is how do I put multiple cell values in a paragraph with conditional statements

This is my tweet format.

(newline)Trade Scalp =IF(E1 = 'LONG' OR 'LONG IDEA' THEN 'Long' ELSE IF E1='SHORT' OR 'SHORT IDEA' THEN 'Short) ${G1}

(newline)

(newline)Entry Price: ${H1}

(newline)Stop Loss: ${I1}

(newline)Take Profit: ${M1}

(newline)R/R Ratio: as much as {J1}

(newline)

(newline)#bitcoin #btc

Comment: Hi, this question is closed 6 hours ago due lack of [details or clarity](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions), Please take a look at [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), include your sheet or images of input and desired output, to make answers informed, precise and easy form the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a formula that will format it how you are asking:

```js
="Trade Scalp "&if(n(REGEXMATCH(upper(E1), "LONG"))>0, "Long", "Short")&" "&G1
&CHAR(10)&
""
&CHAR(10)&
"Entry Price: "&H1
&CHAR(10)&
"Stop Loss: "&I1
&CHAR(10)&
"Take Profit: "&M1
&CHAR(10)&
"R/R Ratio: as much as "&J1
&CHAR(10)&
""
&CHAR(10)&
"#bitcoin #btc"
```

[image]

`CHAR(10)` inserts a line break.

Comment: Works excepts for the regex

Comment: @JohnnyCash I fixed my formula to make the regex independent of case

Comment: It's still always Long even if E1 is Short. Possible values are Long, Long Idea, Short, Short Idea

Comment: @JohnnyCash ohhh my bad, I found my issue. Answer has been updated. Sorry about that!

Comment: Make sure to upvote [helpful questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73026320/19529694)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a list of the tweets meanig in batch.
addition to the answer of [@kaitlynmm569](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11861218/kaitlynmm569), but in this case no [conditional statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_(computer_programming)) no [`REGEXMATCH`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098292?hl=en)

> paste this formula in `H2` and drag down.

```
=IF(B2="",,CONCATENATE(CONCATENATE(B$1,": ",B2," ","g1"),CHAR(10),CHAR(10),JOIN(CHAR(10),TRANSPOSE(ArrayFormula(CONCAT(CONCAT(C$1:F$1,": "),C2:F2)))),CHAR(10),CHAR(10),CONCATENATE(G$1,": ",G2)))
```

You will get a result like this take a look at [this sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1041hBVDn1_jv493NJWWjyWJrgNG4F6df_6sjGwS-WHA/edit?usp=sharing).

[image: Generate a tweet with cell values]

**Steps**...

1 - [`CONCATENATE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094123?hl=en) the header in `B1` "Trade Scalp" and a cell from the same column with `": "` in between and "g1".

2 - [`CONCATENATE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094123?hl=en) that with [`CHAR(10)`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094120?hl=en) which is a line break, and one more [`CHAR(10)`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094120?hl=en).

3 - [`CONCAT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093592?hl=en)`(`[`CONCAT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093592?hl=en)`(C$1:F$1,": "),C2:F2)` and [`JOIN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094077?hl=en) it with [`CHAR(10)`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094120?hl=en) to get the tweet body.

4 - Add anther line breake with [`CHAR(10)`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094120?hl=en),[`CHAR(10)`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094120?hl=en).

5 - [`CONCATENATE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094123?hl=en) the Header "Tags" with Cell of its columns like this [`CONCATENATE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094123?hl=en)`(G$1,": ",G2)`

6 - Lastly [`CONCATENATE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094123?hl=en) everything and wrap it with [`IF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364?hl=en) function to calculate only when not empty like this `=IF(B2="",,CONCATENATE([ Previous formulas ])`.

Comment: @JohnnyCash Make sure to upvote helpful questions, to benefit the responders.